# Trouble conda-installing Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, installation, miniconda

I'm not quite sure what's wrong at the moment. I had Tensorflow working (with a pip3 install I believe), but when I went to install Keras and Theano with miniconda, and also installed tensorflow with conda, TF would not work anymore.

```html
C:\Users\MaartenR\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\python.exe "C:/Users/MaartenR/PycharmProjects/ChipSoft Machine Learning/TF Cluster.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MaartenR\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\MaartenR\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 648, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 560, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MaartenR\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\MaartenR\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\MaartenR\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Users\MaartenR\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/MaartenR/PycharmProjects/ChipSoft Machine Learning/TF Cluster.py", line 5, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\MaartenR\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Users\MaartenR\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\MaartenR\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MaartenR\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\MaartenR\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 648, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 560, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MaartenR\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\MaartenR\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 21, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\MaartenR\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Users\MaartenR\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

By now I'm lost where the problem might lie, I've uninstalled-reinstalled a bunch of modules, manually imported some stuff back and forth, then threw it all away and reinstalled it all from scratch to get the same error.

Theano and Keras work fine by the way, it's just TF that's not budging.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: By conda-installed you mean you did `conda install tensorflow-gpu`? Conda installer support is not official, the suggested installation way is via [`pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.2.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl `](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows). What result do you get with this approach?

Comment: It works! While I'm not sure what the definitive solution was, I uninstalled some (apparently affected) modules and reinstalled them, and then indeed followed your advice and used the pip install, so far it looks like everything runs. Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know conda tries to install packaes that maximise inter-compatibility with other installed packages. From the command they suggest, I'd say Tensorflow doesn't really like this and requires some specific versions (I believe that's why the --ignore-installed at least)